# Bouncing off the edge of a form C#

Tags: c#

I am currently trying to get 3 balls bouncing around the form and have it working, the thing is this part of my code (makes the balls bounce off the edge's of the form) seems very clunky and I feel that it could be condensed somehow. is there a way that I could clean it up

```
public void Move(int width, int height)
        {
            if ((position.X >= 0) && (position.X + size <= width)) //Within X Bounds
            {
                if (XBounce)
                {
                    position.X -= speed;
                }
                else
                {
                    position.X += speed;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (!XBounce)
                {
                    position.X -= size / 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    position.X += size / 2;
                }
                XBounce = !XBounce;
            }

            if ((position.Y >= 0) && (position.Y + size <= height)) //Within Y Bounds
            {
                if (YBounce)
                {
                    position.Y -= speed;
                }
                else
                {
                    position.Y += speed;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (!YBounce)
                {
                    position.Y -= size / 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    position.Y += size / 2;
                }
                YBounce = !YBounce;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Like more appropriate the code-review stack.

Comment: If you changed `XBounce` and `YBounce` to `int` and used values `1` and `-1` you could simply multiply by the bounce direction to get the value to add/subtract. Flipping the sign to change direction is easy enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing `Xbounce` and `YBounce` to `int` variables set to `1` or `-1` you can simplify things a little:

```
public void Move(int width, int height)
    {
        if ((position.X >= 0) && (position.X + size <= width)) //Within X Bounds
        {
            position.X -= XBounce * speed;
        }
        else
        {
            XBounce = -XBounce;
            position.X -= XBounce * size / 2;
        }

        if ((position.Y >= 0) && (position.Y + size <= height)) //Within Y Bounds
        {
                position.Y -= YBounce * speed;
        }
        else
        {
            YBounce = -YBounce;
            position.Y -= YBounce * size / 2;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I like the thinking though the balls just sit there and dont move

Comment: Did you initialize the bounce values to either `1` or `-1`, depending on where the balls start?